# Training Google-Cloud-Automl Model on multiple datasets

Tags: google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I would like to train an automl model on gcp's vertex ai using multiple datasets.  I would like to keep the datasets separate, since they come from different sources, want to train on them separately, etc.  Is that possible?  Or will I need to create a dataset containing both datasets? It looks like I can only select one dataset in the web UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible via the Vertex AI API as long as your sources are in Google Cloud Storage, just provide a list of training data which are in JSON or CSV format that qualifies with the [best practices for formatting of training data](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-image).

See code for creating and importing datasets. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/create-dataset-api#create-dataset) for code reference and further details.

```
from typing import List, Union
from google.cloud import aiplatform

    def create_and_import_dataset_image_sample(
        project: str,
        location: str,
        display_name: str,
        src_uris: Union[str, List[str]], // example: ["gs://bucket/file1.csv", "gs://bucket/file2.csv"]
        sync: bool = True,
    ):
        aiplatform.init(project=project, location=location)
    
        ds = aiplatform.ImageDataset.create(
            display_name=display_name,
            gcs_source=src_uris,
            import_schema_uri=aiplatform.schema.dataset.ioformat.image.single_label_classification,
            sync=sync,
        )
    
        ds.wait()
    
        print(ds.display_name)
        print(ds.resource_name)
        return ds
```

NOTE: The links provided are for Vertex AI AutoML Image. If you access the links there are options for other AutoML products like Text, Tabular and Video.